# read duplicate metrics in extract schema in U-SQL

Tags: analytics, azure-data-lake, u-sql, azure-data-factory

```
` @input =EXTRACT firstname string,name string,name string FROM "/table1.csv"
USING Extractors.Csv(quoting : false, silent : true);
@output =SELECT * FROM @input;

OUTPUT @output TO "/data_output.csv" USING Outputters.Csv(quoting : false); `
```

extract schema contains duplicate metrics (NAME)

How can we read duplicate metrics ?

Answer (score 2):

U-SQL reads columns by position in EXTRACT statement and not by name, so you can call your columns, for example, Name1 and Name2 (or something more logical to your business domain).

```
@input =EXTRACT firstname string,name1 string,name2 string FROM "/table1.csv" 
USING Extractors.Csv(quoting : false);
```

Comment: why you use silent? There is no need to use it here and it's meant for very specific occasions.

Comment: i don't use, its just a copy/paste extractor from initial code (from question). will change it :)